# assistance with mod_rewrite rule returning a 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've spent far too long trying to figure out what is going on with my simple (?) mod_rewite rule to no avail, so here I am.

I have a bunch of rules, all working perfectly, but this one will not, for the life of me work, and throws a 404 on both my local machine, and my live server:

```
RewriteRule ^mywaiver/([0-9]+)\,([0-9]+)/ /waiver_public.php?bid=$1&cid=$2 [L,NC]
```

the aim is to have

```
https://example.com/123456,654321/
```

Be rewritten to

```
https://example.com/waiver_public.php?bid=123456&cid=654321
```

Hitting the url directly (i.e. the version after rewrite) works perfectly, just not the 'clean' version, which simply won't rewrite.

I'm getting nothing in my logs except a 404 in my access log.

Am I missing something really dumb? Any help from another pair of eyes would be amazing at this point.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. All non existing pages will be served by waiver.php file with parameters.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+),(\d+)/?$ waiver.php?bid=$1&cid=$2 [QSA,L]
```